# How to fix org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=503

Tags: java, exception, jsoup

Iam trying to downlaod the research papers I have stored in a list from google scholar by the following code, I have tested the program like 20+ times and about an hour ago, I tested it again and this error pops up. This code is part of my BS final year project and I need to fix this. I've googled the error, and I've tried many things. I need help to overcome this. If I change my ip, will this issue b resolved ?

```
            Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("E:\\ref11.txt"));

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (s.hasNextLine()){
        list.add(s.nextLine());
        {
            for (String Z : list)
            {
                System.out.println(Z);

            }
        }
    }
    //System.out.println("LISTZ:" +list);
    s.close();

        for (String query : list)    

    try {

       //var a= doc.replace(" ","+");

        Document doc = Jsoup
                .connect("https://scholar.google.com.pk/scholar?q=" +query).timeout(30000).followRedirects(true)
      .maxBodySize(1024*1024*3) 
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36")
                .get();
        String title = doc.title();
        System.out.println("title : " + title);
        Elements links = doc.select("div.gs_ggsd").select("a[href]");
        //Element  = doc.select("div.gs_ggs gs_fl").first();
        for (Element link : links) {
            //System.out.println("\nlink : " + link.attr("href"));
            URL website = new URL(link.attr("href"));
    ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\Referenced Papers\\" +title );
    fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
    } 
           // System.out.println("text : " + link.text());
        }
      /* ByteArrayOutputStream href = new ByteArrayOutputStream();



  PrintStream PS = new PrintStream(href);
    PrintStream old = System.out;
    System.setOut(PS);
    System.out.println("Here: " + href.toString());*/


        catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting rate limited by Google for running automated queries against them.

It's common for services to track requests by IP and throttle (here manifesting as a `503 Overloaded`, sometimes given as `429 Too Many Requests` or `403 Forbidden`) or block those requests.

Please be careful to follow the TOS of the sites you're using.